# Do compilers produce better assembly code than humans?

Tags: assembly, compilation

Since I began learning about computer science and programming, my impression was that, in order to obtain higher performance, one would code in a low level language like C, or even MIPS, and to obtain greater portability, a higher level language, like Java or Perl.

However, that was true in the 70s, where compilers produced naive assembly, so an expert human coder could best it. What about today, where modern compilers produce code akin to a master assembly coder?

Is it worth it to learn assembly, like MIPS, when compilers are so much better? Why risk taking a long time to write in a picky and error-prone assembly language?

Comment: It depends on the platform you develop for.  If you write embedded code for devices with limited resources you need to know low level programming even if you actually develop in a compiled language.  You will go back in time when every byte used to count.

Comment: Depends on what kind of human, Agner Fog could do it.  But doing it over and over again, multiple times per day and paying attention to *every* detail is where a human always conks out, Agner too.  It is otherwise the kind of knowledge you'll never be poorer for.

Comment: Compilers are automatically never better than humans, because you can use them, but they can't use you. At worst, you may not find a way to beat it.

Comment: Compilers did produce naive assembly quite into 90s, even early 2000 ... At the moment they produce often over-engineered assembly, where for particular single bottleneck human can often take compiler's output and improve it a bit - then again it takes lot of assembly experience, inner CPU architecture knowledge, and lot of high quality profiling plus understanding what you profile and how does it affect real performance ... if you are somebody new just learning assembly 2-4 years, then you will have hard time to beat half+ of compiler's output. Often it's easier to adjust the C/C++ source.

Comment: Also at the moment only C/C++ (Fortran maybe?) are compiled to native code reasonably, everything else is second league, either due to being too obscure to receive all the effort of compiler producers, or because of the language limits (managed or enforced GC or both). So things like Java with top JIT compilers can be on par with C++ on common small tasks, but if you need anything working over serious piece of data, you can use the C++ low level control over memory model to beat the crap out of the machine, while in Java you are helpless inside the limits of VM. Same story for others (C#, ..).

Comment: So the answer is **no**, they will never do. But the costs of producing better Assembly by human just don't make sense, using good compiler + fixing bottlenecks afterwards will be much cheaper with lot more "bang per dollar". And all of this has to be preceded by high quality architecture and algorithms first, which will make lot more bigger difference than any compiler or language. Whether it is worth to learn the assembly: I would say yes, of course, I can't see how you can really abuse the machine properly without understanding how it works. Plus it's lot of fun.

Comment: They produce much better assembly code than humans could in the same amount of time, which is the real issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilers are made by humans and by definition are no better than the humans that make them.  No a compiler in general cannot outperform some humans.  They can outperform many humans yes, but some humans no, and many of us can examine the output of a compiler and improve at least some of it, depending on the size of the project.

Most compilers don't understand the system, they have been taught in general and perhaps you could tune one, but they don't automatically know your system to know the choices between using memory or not, or tuning for the specific cache for a specific system, etc.

What the compiler can do is not get tired, and can be consistent, and is very fast relative to the human.  So for any sized project, esp a large one the compiler is more than good enough.

Note there is nothing low level about C, and neither JAVA nor Perl make sense along with the word performance.  They are never choices to use if there is even a question of performance, not because of high or low level but because they are slow by design, their goals are different, portability in particular.  More so than C, despite that being a C goal early on.  JAVA somewhat proudly states that it doesn't optimize, and then it is a virtual instruction set on a virtual machine stack based at that.  So it is all about slow. Pascal might have been another choice, in this performance context, or ADA.  The latter two being somewhat rigid and easier to compile and produce tighter code than C so lower level if you will than C.

It is absolutely in your best interest to learn assembly language MIPS or ARM for example.  You would for example have know the answer to your own question.

As mentioned in comments and mentioned pretty much every time this has been asked (why didn't you read the last few dozen questions and answers to this question) let the compiler do the heavy lifting and if you have a really good reason then take the compiler output for a poorly performing section and improve it or if necessary replace it.  Yes you can "carve" a sculpture out of wood using only sand paper, but is it worth it when you can use a chisel and hammer for 80-90 percent of the work and then sand from there?  In the case of programming it is very rare you need to sand at all, unless you don't know how to use the compiler, which you won't if you don't know how to read its output (assembly language).

As well as the number of times this has been asked at SO, there are also many times folks have asked "why did the compiler do this" pointing out places that may or may not be the most optimal solution.  Many, sure are why so much stack on main(), not a performance question.

The other problem here is definition of performance.  For x86 targets, there are way too many different processors and motherboards.  If you were to tune for one specific chip on a specific motherboard with specific memory with specific peripherals, that may be great for that system, but will make many other similar x86 systems run slower.  ARM same problem, but different.  Benchmarks are bogus because they are so easy to manipulate, so before you can even go down this path you need to define for yourself what performance means.  And then try to get the compiler to do that, and then examine the output, and then decide if you can or even want to improve upon it.

No, compilers are made by humans and are no smarter nor better than humans. They are at best more consistent and certainly much faster while remaining more consistent.

Comment: "JAVA somewhat proudly states that it doesnt optimize" - Whoa, that's a strong statement. And your conclusion that "it is all about slow" is incorrect: The Java compiler does not optimize for a reason: to produce *simple* bytecode which the JIT can then better optimize if, when, and how, at runtime, it actually makes sense.

Comment: So I guess we should stop optimizing compiling to machine code in general and the processor do the optimization at run time?  Doesnt make sense in that case nor in the JAVA case, at run time is too late and too slow, JAVA bytecode is an instruction set, no reason not to optimize when compiling to an instruction set.

Comment: If runtime, just in time, optimization were the better solution then we would see operating systems doing this as the norm, but we dont we see dead code and other improvements at compile time not run time.  So why would one instruction set be special?  It isnt.

Comment: Java is special because one "binary" application runs on many different platforms. The AOT compiler cannot know which optimizations are adequate because it cannot know the platform the program will be executed on. Also, the AOT compiler cannot know the hotspots of the program at runtime, which the JIT can, and it can also dynamically adjust to changing conditions at runtime.

Comment: The point is the inverse of your argument: *If* you need bytecode (for platform-independence) in the first place, then make that code so (simple) that it can be optimized to the conditions at runtime as much as you can. If you don't need/have bytecode (OS,...) then a JIT compiler does make much less sense (- any?). Also, performance-critical AOT-compiled code will often be optimized with profiling data gathered through (artificial) performance tests. So it is pretty good for the known target platform and the anticipated use case; not much to be gained by further runtime optimization.

Comment: I guess we have to agree to disagree...

Comment: With that I agree :)